# registry.byID set content returns Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, dojo

Trying to set the content of content pane with registry.byId, but I'm not able to get the object -- I get the following error:

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference

my code is like this:

```
 require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", 
"dojox/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
 function (parser, dom, registry) {

parser.parse();

registry.byId("Content").set("content", "Test Content");//Content ID is not being found

 });

</script>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" id="Main" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="TOC" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'leading'">
 TOC
 </div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="Content" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'center'">
 </div>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the widgets are in the process of being created and they are not ready yet when you call the **registry.byId()** call.

you need to add the initialization code in the ready() call by including the "dojo/ready" module.

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready",
          "dojox/layout/ContentPane"],
function (parser, dom, registry, ready) {

   parser.parse();
   ready( function(){

      // your code goes here.
      registry.byId("Content").set("content", "Test Content");

   });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that since dojo 1.8, the `parser.parse()` call returns an [array with a Promise mixed in](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.8#async-nature-of-parse), so the recommended way of interacting with parsed objects is

```
parser.parse().then(function(){
    registry.byId('content'.set('content','test content');
});
```

Using dojo/ready should achieve the same effect though.